# PHP PDO Values for setAttributes() of PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT and PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY

Tags: php, pdo, attributes, variable-types

Looking at the documentation of the [PDO::setAttribute](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php) for example the paragraph of:

> PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES

the description states:

> Convert numeric values to strings when fetching. **Requires bool**

so it is obvious how to set that attribute:

```
$dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, true);

// or
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_STRINGIFY_FETCHES, false);
```

but these don't have any information about values they accept

```
PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY
```

Therefore I have a few questions:

1. Do the attributes `PDO::ATTR_AUTOCOMMIT` and `PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY` accept `bool` values?
2. Is there any reference to the values they accept?

Comment: If it sounds like a boolean, it is.

Comment: Just look for the class constants section in either main PDO manual page or a specific driver's page